# Python script to Export multiple MXDs to JPG

Tags: arcpy, python, error, mxd, jpg

I have a project where I have many MXDs in one folder, and would like to export each one to JPGs in another folder. I've been stumped with a particular error message I'm running in to:

> Runtime error
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "string", line 5, in module
>
> WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'T:\Projects\t TIP\FY2018\New folder/*.*'

This is the code I'm using:

```
 import arcpy, os
 inputPath = 'T:\Projects\411 TIP\FY2018\FY2018 TIP Database.gdb'
 outputPath = 'T:\Projects\411 TIP\TIP Database\Project_Maps\2019'
 #Loop through each MXD file for filename in os.listdir(inputPath):    
 for filename in os.listdir(inputPath): 
    fullpath = os.path.join(inputPath, filename)     
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath):         
        if filename.lower().endswith(".mxd"):              
 #Reference MXD and export             
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)             
 arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, outputPath + "\\" + filename + ".jpg")
```

I apologize if this is a simple fix, I am new to using python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for path variables use this **r"this\is\your\path"**
the r stands for 'raw' it tells python this is a path string.

Comment: This suggestion cleared the error, however it only produced one .jpg in the target folder called "timestamp.jpg." Any idea why this is or how to correct it?

Comment: Yah your export jpg command is outside of your loop

Answer (score 1):

I've used this script when I want to loop through a folder that contains MXD files that are to be converted to PNG with a resolution of 600 pixels. Change the PNG to JPEG as well as the folderpath

```
 import arcpy, os

 folderPath = r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\demographic_siteselection"  
 for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):  
 fullpath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)  
 if os.path.isfile(fullpath):  
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullpath)  
    if extension.lower() == ".mxd":  
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)  
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, basename + '.png', resolution = 600)
```